# How to combine two HashMaps only if key not present?

Tags: java

I am combining two HashMaps in Java.
I don't want the `hs2` values to override the values in `hs1`,
I want to combine only if not present.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Object,String> hs1 = new HashMap<>();
        hs1.put(1, "ram");
        hs1.put(2, "sita");

        HashMap<Object,String> hs2 = new HashMap<>();

        hs2.put(2, "test");
        hs2.put(5, "fre");

        HashMap<Object,String> hs3 = new HashMap<>() ;//Map is which we add

        hs3.putAll(hs1);
        hs3.putAll(hs2);

        System.out.println(" hs3 : " + hs3);
    }
}
```

Expected Result :

**{1=ram, 5=fre, 2=sita}**

Comment: what do you mean by combine? if  hs1.put(2,"sita"); and hs1.put(2,"test"); exist, what is your expected result?

Comment: I am almost certain your expected output is not what you expect.

Comment: Why would two correspond to "ram", do you mean "sita"?

Comment: Sorry , i have modified my expected result

Answer (score 6):

> I don't want the hs2 to override the Values of hs1 I want to combine only if not present

In that case, add the entries of `hs2` first, and then add the entries of `hs1`:

```
HashMap<Object,String> hs3 = new HashMap<>(hs2);
hs3.putAll(hs1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, I see to do this would be somehting like:

```
hs2.forEach(hs1::putIfAbsent);
```

Comment: Doesn’t that modify `hs1`?